# Why is defaultValue not working in React select element

Tags: reactjs, select, styled-components

I have a react select component which is being styled with `styled-components`. I want the select to be uncontrolled so that the parent stores state and handles changes. It works as expected except for the default value. I am passing in `defaultId` which I want to use to set the `defaultValue` of the select. It is not working though and is selecting the first value of the employees array instead. Any ideas why?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Select = styled.select`
  // some styles here
`;

const EmployeeDropdown = ({ handleEmployeeChange, defaultId }) => {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // getting data and then setEmployees here.
    // employees is an array of objects, each object having an id and a name
  }, []);

  return (
    <Select
      onChange={handleEmployeeChange}
      defaultValue={defaultId}
    >
      {employees.length > 0 ? (
        employees.map(person => {
          return (
            <option
              value={person.id}
              key={person.id}
            >
              {person.name}
            </option>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <option value={''}>Loading...</option>
      )}
    </Select>
  );
};

export default EmployeeDropdown;
```

Comment: "*It is not working*" ... what's `defaultId` and what's it supposed to be?

Comment: @Aleksandar `defaultId` is the id of some employee in the array. As I said, the select should be defaulting to the option with this value. Instead, it is defaulting to the first element in the array